# увеличить шаг прокрутки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделана прокрутка div колесиком.
Но шаг ее 1,так как chet++ и chet--.Как можно изменить на 10 например?

```
var chet = 5;
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = getDelta(e);
    $("#container").scrollTop(delta < 0 ? chet++ : chet--);
});

function getDelta(e) {
    var evt = window.event || e;
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
    return evt.detail ? evt.detail * (-40) : evt.wheelDelta
}
```

Весь пример http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/r3c3fqv8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/r3c3fqv8/3/

```
var step = 10; // вместо шага в 1, сделаем 10
$("#container").scrollTop(delta < 0 ? chet += step : chet -= step);
```

И я бы порекомендовал использовать проверенную либо для прокрутки колёсиком: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel